# Unexpected token ILLEGAL while assigning Razor Code to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using JavaScript to dynamically add rows to a table  using ASP .NET MVC's Razor syntax.Assigning a text-box to a variable works fine However, when I want to assign a drop-down list , it throw's an error - "Unexpected Illegal Token".

```
   var expH = '@Html.DropDownList("TransDebit[{id}].Expenditure_Head",new SelectList(ViewBag.ExpCodes,"Expenditure_Code","Expenditure_Code"))';
```

Converts to (As seen from chrome's console) :

```
var expH = '<select id="TransDebit__id___Expenditure_Head" name="TransDebit[{id}].Expenditure_Head"><option value="313">313</option>
<option value="414">414</option>
</select>';
```

Which is exactly what I want but why does it throw an error ? I can't see anything wrong with it.
Please Help.
Thanks.
EDIT 1: SCREENSHOT
[image]

Comment: I doubt very much that that's what you want since it would never bind to anything. What is `{id}`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I replace {id} to datetime to assign each one a unique id.

Comment: Why would it never bind to anything?

Comment: Because if you want to bind to a collection it needs to be `name="TransDebit[0].Expenditure_Head"`, `name="TransDebit[1].Expenditure_Head"` etc. If you want to dynamically add collection items, suggest you look at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)

Comment: what if I replace `{id}` by count ? by using `ExpH.replace("{id}", count)`

Comment: The problem is your have invalid `{` and `}` characters - but look at the links I gave you to understand how to do this correctly.

Comment: Ok .I will read your links. Strange Though `var ExpH = '@Html.TextBox("TransDebit[{id}].Expenditure_Head")'` works completely fine.

Comment: Can you provide your Viewbag data?? I am trying to replicate your issue on my side

Comment: @Reddy ViewBag.ExpCodes data contains two values as shown :313 and 414.

Comment: `Unexpected token ILLEGAL` this error is because your Razor expression rendered in multiple lines and javascript cant find a proper line ending and throws as error. you can notice that there is not string concatenation

Comment: What you can do is render it properly in Razor code but keep it hidden and then access it from the javascript code and use it.

Comment: @Reddy Yeah ,  I just did that :) .Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks To [Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) , I have finally found a work-around. What I did was create an hidden div only for this variable:

```
<div id="NewDebit" style="display:none">

 @Html.DropDownList("TransDebit[{id}].Expenditure_Head", new SelectList(ViewBag.ExpCodes, "Expenditure_Code", "Expenditure_Code"),"Select Expenditure Code")

</div>
```

and the in my java script code:

```
var ExpH = document.getElementById("NewDebit").innerHTML;
```

This works great , I think the error might be there due to some character escape issue.